# Json.net format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having trouble with json formation for an api call. I need something like this

```
{
    "token": "87dd8f93-27ad-493c-8ab1-e75c50b8fb71",
    "answers": [
        {
            "question": "Where are you from",
            "ans": "t"
        },
        {
            "question": "I am from tts",
            "ans": "f"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have array of hashes named answers which i made separately with something like

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
```

after that i have to make with the token but then using the same process i got

```
{
    "token": "87dd8f93-27ad-493c-8ab1-e75c50b8fb71",
    "answers": [
        "{\r\n
            \"question\": \"Where are you from\",
            \"ans\": \"t\"
        }",
        "{\r\n
            \"question\": \"I am from tts\",
            \"ans\": \"f\"
        }"
    ]
}

 public class Account
    {
       public string question { get; set; }
       public string ans { get; set; }           
    }
```

and after that

```
if (ansNo.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        Account account = new Account
                        {
                            question = quizText.Text,
                            ans = "f"
                        };
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
                        Globals.answers[counter] = json;   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Account account = new Account
                        {
                            question = quizText.Text,
                            ans = "t"
                        };
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
                        Globals.answers[counter] = json;
                    }
```

need help please
Thanks

Comment: If you're just passing it into an api call, why do you care if it's indented? The function that you're calling certainly doesn't :)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling because due to '"' on curly braces in answer it is not proper json, and not getting any result back

Comment: @L.B it is adding quotes on curly braces in answers.

Comment: How do you fill `account`?

Comment: @user2752370 What does that have to do with the indented format?

Comment: @user2752370 I can not generate your case. post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: is it because you are serialising the object twice? `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);` do you then serialise the Globals object?

Comment: as i told the quotes creating problem. because of the quotes that is not a valid JSON and because of that i am not getting any response.

Comment: @Adween yap i think so . but is there any other way i can get the desire result ???

Comment: Is this using asp.net WebAPI? If so the default serializer could be serializing it again, if so there isn't a need for you to serialize it manually. Here are the details on how serialization works by default in WebAPI http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: no! its a custom api written in node.js.

Comment: Sory @L.B didn't notice your comment about SSCCE . can you please specify what really you want. because i think it will executable example will be difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after can be achieved by a rejig of your data. Create a new object to serialise to return

```
public class MyJson{
    public string token {get;set;}
    public List<Account> answers {get;set;}

    public MyJson(){
        answers = new List<Account>();
    }
}
```

Create a new MyJson object and add the token

```
MyJson o = new MyJson { token = "87dd8f93-27ad-493c-8ab1-e75c50b8fb71" }
```

Then like you already have add to the answers to the list

```
Account account = new Account{
     question = quizText.Text,
     ans = "t"
};
o.answers.Add(account);
```

Then serialise the whole thing and return it

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Adwin thanks for the example. I have tried it. but having an issue. The answers list doesn't getting any thing. its empty ....

Comment: account object as hashes? not sure what you mean by that... The account list object should populate in the `if (ansNo.IsChecked == true)` if statement, there should be an item added if that if statement is reached.

Comment: Adween yap i tried that in conditional statements and by hashes i mean  i have a question text like ("where are you from") and an answer like ("t" or "f"). i want them as hashes like {"question":"where are you fro","ans":"t"}, and all hashes in one array and then that array and token is one parent hash.

Comment: Ahh ok, To make them hashes i would use a `Dictionary<string, string> answers {get;set;}` instead of a of list of account. then yes they would be hashed, however why do you need them to be hashed? it doesn't really matter when they are sent as json...

Comment: ok got your point about hashes but it is not adding account in answers list .... got any idea ?

Comment: can you pop the code you now have for the entire method on and i might be able to spot something

Comment: Adween i think its all i got . user ans a question. i get question and ans. it may b round about 50 questions. after that i have to arrange each question and ans in one hash and put that in an array of "answers". Then creating json with "token" have to call the api.

Comment: Api is custom api and in node. and it requires JSON as described on top.

Comment: Thanks for your help... i got my solution.